# Image fades into background React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, linear-gradients

I am making a react native app, and I'm having trouble getting an image to fade at the edges so that it blends into the background. I want it to look like the Netflix app, where the image doesn't end, but just fades into black [Netflix image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93l7h.jpg). I have tried wrapping my image component in a linear gradient, but that doesn't get rid of the hard edges of the image. I have to turn to opacity of the image all the way down to 0.1 to get that, which just destroys the quality of the image.

Here is the code for the component:

```
 <LinearGradient
     colors={["black", "white", "black"]}
     locations={[0.2, 0.5, .8]}
>
   <Image
      key={image}
      source={{ uri: image }}
      style={styles.backgroundImage}
    />
  </LinearGradient>
```

and the styles:

```
imageGradient: {
    height: "70%",
    marginTop: 150,
    justifyContent: "center"
  },

  backgroundImage: {
    height: "80%",
    width: DEVICE_WIDTH,
    opacity: 0.8
  }
```

Comment: Did either response answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Render Linear gradient absolutely above the image

also the colors should not be white, if you want the transparent color then use #00000000 to give transparent gradient

colors={['#000000', '#00000000', '#000000']}

[Snack Link](https://snack.expo.dev/@ashwith00/image-gradient)

code :

```
 <View>
        <Image
          source={{
            uri: 'https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg',
          }}
          style={styles.backgroundImage}
        />
        <LinearGradient
          style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject }}
          colors={['#000000', '#00000000', '#000000']}
          locations={[0.2, 0.5, 0.8]}
        />
 </View>
```

[image: 2]

Comment: This doesn't get rid of the edges of the image still

Comment: change the colors value to ['#000000', '#00000000', '#000000'] if you want to completely remove ovelap the image edges

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to make the `Image` partially transparent, you can make the `LinearGradient` *on top* of the `Image` transparent near the bottom.

For example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
          <Image style={{width: 300, height: 300}} source={require('./assets/snack-icon.png')} />
          <LinearGradient
            colors={['transparent','rgba(0,0,0,1.0)']}
            style={{position: 'absolute', width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
          />
      </View>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable url.
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'white'
  },
});
```

Snack link: https://snack.expo.dev/IWy50EQiX

[image]